# How to solve for effective interest rate including fees?

Tags: exponential-function, finance

I have gotten very stuck on a math problem involving interest rates when combined with flat fees and cashback incentives. I am looking to determine an "effective interest rate" so that two loans with different fees, rates, and incentives can be compared.

Here's what I've got so far...

$$ COST = \frac{r}{12} \cdot P \cdot t \cdot \frac{(1+\frac{r}{12})^t}{(1+\frac{r}{12})^t-1}+f-c $$

where r is the annual interest rate, P is the principal, t is the term, f is the fee, and c is the cashback incentive.

Of these variables, I know everything needed to calculate COST.

My question is... how can I "unwind" COST to get to an "effective" interest rate?

$$ COST = \frac{R}{12}\cdot P\cdot t\cdot \frac{(1+\frac{R}{12})^t}{(1+\frac{R}{12})^t-1}$$

Where P and t are known. I've gotten as far as this...

$$ \frac{12\cdot COST}{P\cdot t}=\frac{R\cdot(1+\frac{R}{12})^t}{(1+\frac{R}{12})^t-1}$$

But now I'm stuck. How can I solve for R from here?

Comment: Seems highly nonlinear. I would just put this thing to a calculator and numerically find $R$.

Comment: Where did you get that COST formula and what does it mean?

Comment: COST represents the total amount paid on a loan of principal P, with an annual interest rate of r, with t monthly payments, plus fees f and cashback c. It's derived from the monthly payment formula $$COST=\frac{\frac{r}{12}P(1+\frac{r}{12})^t}{ (1+\frac{r}{12})^t-1} $$
then I add fees f and subtract cashback c.

I got it from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator)

Comment: That's the formula for the monthly payment, which it seems you simply add up without discounting payments according to when they are made. So in the end you have neither the present value nor the future value of the stream of payments. I don't think this is a good way to compute effective interest rates at all.

Comment: The way I would look at it is, compute the monthly payment, now take the amount $P - f + c$ (which is the net amount the lender actually handed over to you at the start of the loan) and using _that_ amount as principal (instead of $P$), find the interest rate $R$ that gives me the same monthly payment the lender asked me to make.

Comment: After I try rewriting the problem that way, I end up with...
$$ \frac{12*payment}{P+f-c}=\frac{R*(1+\frac{R}{12})^t}{(1+\frac{R}{12})^t-1} $$
So... a known value on the left and the exact same equation on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I have done it when I was looking at loans:

First, convert the annual rate to a monthly rate $r$ (so we don't clutter the formulas with all those "divide by $12$"s).
Set $t$ to the number of monthly payments.

Nominally, you are borrowing principal $P.$ That is how the lender computes the monthly payments. If the annual rate is $r$ and you make $t$ payments, starting one month *after* you receive the loan amount, the lender should ask for a monthly payment equal to
$$
A = \frac{r}{1 - (1 + r)^{-t}} P.
$$

But in actual reality, after paying $f$ fees and getting $c$ cash back,
you end up receiving a net amount of only $P - f + c$ from the lender at the start of the loan. That is the amount the lender *really* lent to you; the nominal amount $P,$ the fees, and the cash back are all just window dressing around this amount.
But you still have to pay the amount $A$ each month that the lender asked for.
So the *effective* monthly interest rate is the rate $R$ that satisfies this equation:
$$
A = \frac{R}{1 - (1 + R)^{-t}} (P - f + c).
$$

I think this will usually need to be solved numerically, that is, there is not a neat "closed-form" formula to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @David K's answer, let $k=\frac A{P-f+c}$ to make the equation
$$\frac{R}{1 - (1 + R)^{-t}}=k$$ which does not show explicit solutions and which will then require some numerical method (Newton being probably the simplest).

However, we can make quite good approximations since we know that $R \ll 1$.

Then, using Taylor series, this would give 
$$\frac{R}{1 - (1 + R)^{-t}}=\frac{1}{t}+\frac{ (t+1)}{2 t}R+\frac{ t^2-1}{12 t}R^2-
   \frac{t^2-1}{24 t}R^3-\frac{ t^4-20
   t^2+19}{720 t}R^4+\frac{ t^4-10 t^2+9}{480 t}R^5+\frac{
   2 t^6-147 t^4+1008 t^2-863}{60480 t}R^6+O\left(R^7\right)$$ and using [series reversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html)
$$\color{blue}{R=x-\frac{t-1}{6} x^2+\frac{2 t^2-t-1}{36} 
   x^3-\frac{22 t^3+3 t^2-18 t-7}{1080}x^4+\frac{52 t^4+44
   t^3-39 t^2-46 t-11}{6480}x^5-\frac{300 t^5+484 t^4-43 t^3-447 t^2-253 t-41}{90720}x^6+O\left(x^7\right)}$$ where $\color{blue}{x=\frac{2 (k t-1)}{t+1}}$.

To make an example, let us use $k=\frac 1 {100}$ and $t=120$ and let $R_{(n)}$ be the computed interest rate obtained using the expansion to $O\left(x^n\right)$. The results would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & R_{(n)} \\
 1 & 0.0033057851 \\
 2 & 0.0030890422 \\
 3 & 0.0031178218 \\
 4 & 0.0031136135 \\
 5 & 0.0031142750 \\
 6 & 0.0031141662
\end{array}
\right)$$
while the exact solution would be $R=0.0031141827$.

For more simplicity, we can transform (for the same accuracy) the long formula as a Padé approximant
$$\color{blue}{R=x \frac{1+\frac{t+1}{2}  x+\frac{2 t^2+5 t+2}{45}  x^2 } {1+\frac{2 t+1}{3} x+\frac{6 t^2+5 t+1}{60} x^2 }}$$